# Android: Scroll to a specific view in ListView on clicking a select view

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a `LinearLayout`. One side has an `alphabetic index` of words just like a dictionary and the other one has a `ListView`. I would like to scroll the listview to a specific view on clicking a letter in alphabetic index while keeping this index view constant.

Comment: I have created the ListView. From there, I have no idea how to scroll based on a selection. I know it must be something simple. Scrolling to a specific view based on its position in listview would do it but cant get the exact way

Comment: Did you create listeners for your *aplhabetic index*? You need to get the click event somehow.

Comment: Yes. alphabetic index would be a list view non-scrollable and I can handle the event and get exactly what index has been clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have registered listeners on your alphabetic index and know to which item you want to scroll to, you can use `smoothScrollToPosition` (added in API 8) on the listview like:

```
mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

If you have a lot of items you may want to use `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop` (added in API 11) to make the scrolling faster. Like this:

```
mListView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, offset, duration);
```

*Offset* here is from where do you want the scrolling to start and *duration* is obviously how long it will take. You can implement your own algorithms to calculate those values for optimal scrolling experience.

Comment: Precisely what I needed.